# $(this) not working on delegate()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some simple code that creates elements on an event, one of the elements is a button and this button has a click event.

```
<button id="' + packageNum.toString() + '" class="package-dup package-add-dup-' +
packageNum.toString() + '" title="Add Duplicate Parcel">Duplicate Parcel</button>' +
```

I am just trying to get the id attribute from this button on the button click event.

```
$(function () {
    $("body").delegate(".package-dup", "click", function () {
       alert($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

This shows the $(this).attr('id') element as undefined.

If i try and use a normal

```
$('.package-dup').click(function () { .... }
```

The click event does not work at all.

Using jquery 2.0.3

Comment: Try using `.on()`. And `$(this)` works fine with it.

Comment: Which jQuery version do you have?

Comment: You're missing the closing paran on the alert syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try using on() and fixing the syntax errors :

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.package-dup', function () {
       alert( this.id );
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4yXTr/)

Comment: hmm it works in the fiddle, but that button is actually being created on an event and is not in the html directly. The .on() does nothing and acts just like the normal .click(). I am wondering if i need to somehow delegate a button that has not been created yet on the event before.

Comment: @gerdi this syntax of .on() method is using delegation. You should really read the DOC

Comment: Did you open the console and check for errors in your code? Did you doublecheck the classes etc ?

Comment: And this works just fine with dynamic elements as well -> http://jsfiddle.net/4yXTr/1/

Comment: @adeneo I am been reading an checking for about 4 hours now .. I dont know why it is working in jsfiddle and not my code but its not. I would really like to post all the code but there is a heck of a lot in that little section. Also the event.target.id is working .. thanks A. Wolff

Comment: @adeneo thank you aswell. I really appreciate everyone on this site for helping out noobs like me

Comment: If `event.target.id` is working, but not `this.id`, your HTML is not the same as what you've posted! The ID you're trying to get is on a nested element, otherwise `this` and `event.target` would be the same element, as it's not, `.package-dup` is somehow the parent element to whatever you're actually clicking.